# Position link with CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="impressum">
    <a class="impressumstyle" href="https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl">Impressum</a>       
</div>
```

And in my CSS file:

```
.impressum {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
top: 275px;
background: transparent;
text-align: left;}

.impressumstyle {
font-family: Verdana;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;}

.impressumstyle:hover {
color: #8d8d8d;}
```

My problem is, that the link, when i use the top-value in .impressum, does not work anymore. And it does not change its color anymore as well..where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work properly: https://jsfiddle.net/b9ku0xj0/

Answer (score 0):

try to target your ling directly through whole structure

```
.impressum .impressumstyle:hover {
color: #8d8d8d;}
```

or

```
.impressum a:hover {
color: #8d8d8d;}
```

or, if you wish to use the hover trigger over .impressum, use

```
.impressum:hover *{
color: #8d8d8d;}
```

or also this should work:

```
.impressum:hover a{
color: #8d8d8d;}
```

but beware, in some cases, using hover efect on parent element, if you want to change only its child, may not work, it depends on size of parent element. Especially with combination of absolute positioning, you can hover your link, but you actually not hovering its parent element in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys, i put this div into another, major div. the top value positioned this underneath the major div, that's why it doesn't work..